# Getting "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python, conda

I'm new to Python, and keep getting a "syntax error".  With Windows 7, I start in command prompt, and enter the python terminal.  I receive the warning

> Warning:  This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated. Libraries may fail to load. To activate this environment please see https://conda.io/activation.

Following the instructions there, I enter:

```
conda activate myenv
```

(with myenv replaced with the folder containing the path to python.exe) It seems I always get

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It looks like you’re typing the command in the Python *interpreter*, not the OS *terminal*.

Comment: Type it at a prompt *before* you enter "the python terminal"

Comment: If I enter this into command prompt I then get: 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: I'll add that I have Anaconda3 installed currently, but I tried this with a fresh install of just the python interpreter, and I would still get the syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enter `conda activate myenv` before starting python, if I understand it correctly

Comment: If I enter this into command prompt I then get:  'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://appuals.com/fix-conda-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or-batch-file/